# how to catch astyanax failures in asynchronous executions

Tags: java, asynchronous, cassandra, astyanax

The project I work on uses astyanax driver to access Cassandra. I want to implement an asynchronous operation:

```
MutationBatch m;
//…
ListenableFuture<OperationResult<Void>> lf = m.executeAsync();
lf.addListener(myRunnableCallback, myExecutor);
```

Question: assuming the exception was not thrown right away within `executeAsync()` call, how do I distinguish between successful and failed executions?

The only way I can think of is that when the completion callback is invoked `lf.get()` throws an exception in case of failure. If this is the right way, is there a document or lines in astyanax sources confirming that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround: instead of `ListenableFuture`'s `addListener` method taking `Runnable` parameter I can use `Futures.addCallback(ListenableFuture<V>, FutureCallback<V>, Executor)`. `FutureCallback` has 2 methods: `onSuccess` and `onFailure`. That solves my problem.

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained